# Core Plot and displaying y label

Tags: ios, core-plot

I've run into some issues with displaying my y axis labels properly with iOS and Core Plot...

I'll show you the two different scenarios I currently have, and hopefully someone can help me get one of them working properly...

Okay, so first scenario:
The code:

```
// Configure y-axis
CPTAxis *y = axisSet.yAxis;
y.axisLineStyle = axisLineStyle;
y.majorGridLineStyle = customGridStyle;
y.labelingPolicy = CPTAxisLabelingPolicyAutomatic;
y.labelTextStyle = axisTextStyle;
y.majorTickLineStyle = axisLineStyle;
y.majorTickLength = 0.0f;
y.minorTickLength = 0.0f;
y.tickDirection = CPTSignNegative;
NSInteger majorIncrement = [self findStep:(maxValue - minValue)/7];
CGFloat yMax = [self findMaximumValue:maxValue];
NSMutableSet *yLabels = [NSMutableSet set];
NSMutableSet *yMajorLocations = [NSMutableSet set];

int maxLocation = 0;

for (NSInteger j = 0; j <= yMax + majorIncrement; j += majorIncrement) {
    CPTAxisLabel *label = [[CPTAxisLabel alloc] initWithText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i", j] textStyle:y.labelTextStyle];
    NSDecimal location = CPTDecimalFromInteger(j);
    label.tickLocation = location;
    label.offset = 125;

    if (label) {
        [yLabels addObject:label];
    }

    [yMajorLocations addObject:[NSDecimalNumber decimalNumberWithDecimal:location]];
    if (maxLocation < [[NSDecimalNumber decimalNumberWithDecimal:location] intValue]) {
        maxLocation = [[NSDecimalNumber decimalNumberWithDecimal:location] intValue];
    }
}

y.gridLinesRange = [CPTPlotRange plotRangeWithLocation:CPTDecimalFromInteger(0) length:CPTDecimalFromInteger(maxLocation)];
y.axisLabels = yLabels;
y.majorTickLocations = yMajorLocations;
```

Now this code works to a certain extent... See my screenshots below:
[image: Core Plot] [image: Core Plot 2]

Here the part I would love to change is the decimal... I want to change the location decimal to now show a .0...

2. scenario (the one I would really liked fixed)
   To save you the trouble of reading the below code, I can point out that the big change here is

   y.labelingPolicy = CPTAxisLabelingPolicyNone;

Code:

```
// Configure y-axis
CPTAxis *y = axisSet.yAxis;
y.axisLineStyle = axisLineStyle;
y.majorGridLineStyle = customGridStyle;
y.labelingPolicy = CPTAxisLabelingPolicyNone;
y.labelTextStyle = axisTextStyle;
y.majorTickLineStyle = axisLineStyle;
y.majorTickLength = 0.0f;
y.minorTickLength = 0.0f;
y.tickDirection = CPTSignPositive;
NSInteger majorIncrement = [self findStep:(maxValue - minValue)/7];
CGFloat yMax = [self findMaximumValue:maxValue];
NSMutableSet *yLabels = [NSMutableSet set];
NSMutableSet *yMajorLocations = [NSMutableSet set];

int maxLocation = 0;

for (NSInteger j = 0; j <= yMax + majorIncrement; j += majorIncrement) {
    CPTAxisLabel *label = [[CPTAxisLabel alloc] initWithText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i", j] textStyle:y.labelTextStyle];
    NSDecimal location = CPTDecimalFromInteger(j);
    label.tickLocation = location;
    label.offset = -25;

    if (label) {
        [yLabels addObject:label];
    }

    [yMajorLocations addObject:[NSDecimalNumber decimalNumberWithDecimal:location]];
    if (maxLocation < [[NSDecimalNumber decimalNumberWithDecimal:location] intValue]) {
        maxLocation = [[NSDecimalNumber decimalNumberWithDecimal:location] intValue];
    }
}

y.gridLinesRange = [CPTPlotRange plotRangeWithLocation:CPTDecimalFromInteger(0) length:CPTDecimalFromInteger(maxLocation)];
y.axisLabels = yLabels;
y.majorTickLocations = yMajorLocations;
x.gridLinesRange = [CPTPlotRange plotRangeWithLocation:CPTDecimalFromInteger(0) length:CPTDecimalFromInteger(maxLocation)];
```

and the plot come out as:

[image: Core Plot 3][image: Core Plot 4][image: Core Plot 5]

Now here a lot of y axises are missing...

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With the `CPTAxisLabelingPolicyNone` labeling policy, you are in complete control of the tick locations and labels. It's up to you to decide how many ticks and labels to make and where to put them.

If all you want to do is change the number format on the axis, keep the `CPTAxisLabelingPolicyAutomatic` labeling policy (or any one of the others except `CPTAxisLabelingPolicyNone`), remove the code that creates tick locations and labels, and change the `labelFormatter`. You can use any `NSFormatter`. Create an `NSNumberFormatter`, configure it to display the desired number format, and set it to the `labelFormatter` property.

Comment: Thanks, Eric! I really want to get create the labels with the None Policy, where I can control the steps and such better, but for now I used the solution with formatting the labelFormatter, until I get the other part working better... Thanks!